# How to prevent a page event to trigger in jquery mobile

Tags: ajax, events, jquery-mobile

The following events are called when transitioning from page A to page B:

- pagebeforechange
- pagebeforeload
- pagebeforecreate
- pagecreate
- pageinit
- pageload
- pagebeforechange (yes, again)
- pagebeforeshow
- pageshow
- pagechange

I'd like to stop that chain of events at some point to load some dynamic data via AJAX and then restart the chain of events to show a fully complete page.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. Unless you do something like run a loop in a handler bound to one of those events... in which case you might most likely end up with an unresponsive script.

You could either invoke `changePage` as last step of your Ajax `success` handler. Or you could transition to the target `toPage` and show a loading animation until your Ajax returns.